# Terraform - How to pass variable in json body with quotes

Tags: json, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create AWS Cloudwatch dashboard using terraform. I am trying to variabilize the query part of the code using map type.

My code is as below,

**variable.tf**

```
variable "query" {

  type = map
  default = {
    CPU_Utilization = "\"SELECT AVG(CPUUtilization) FROM SCHEMA(\"AWS/EC2\", InstanceId) WHERE InstanceId = 'i-1dihfahfehf'\", \"label\": \"Query1\", \"id\": \"q1\""
}
}

variable "metrics_name" {
  default = "CPU_Utilization"
}
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "metrics" {

  dashboard_name = var.metrics_name

  dashboard_body = jsonencode(
  {
    "widgets": [
        {
            "type": "metric",
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "width": 6,
            "height": 6,
            "properties": {
                "view": "timeSeries",
                "stacked": false,
                "metrics": [
                    [ { "expression": "${var.query["CPU_Utilization"]}" } ]
                ],
                "region": "eu-west-1",
                "stat": "Average",
                "period": 300,
                "title": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
  )
  
}
```

When i do terraform plan/apply, i am getting the below output

```
  aws_cloudwatch_dashboard.metrics will be created
  + resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "metrics" {
      + dashboard_arn  = (known after apply)
      + dashboard_body = jsonencode(
            {
              + widgets = [
                  + {
                      + height     = 6
                      + properties = {
                          + metrics = [
                              + [
                                  + {
                                      + expression = "\"SELECT AVG(CPUUtilization) FROM SCHEMA(\"AWS/EC2\", InstanceId) WHERE InstanceId = 'i-0d9af97eeeaca30a5'\", \"label\": \"Query1\", \"id\": \"q1\""
                                    },
                                ],
                            ]
                          + period  = 300
                          + region  = "eu-west-1"
                          + stacked = false
                          + stat    = "Average"
                          + title   = ""
                          + view    = "timeSeries"
                        }
                      + type       = "metric"
                      + width      = 6
                      + x          = 0
                      + y          = 0
                    },
                ]
            }
        )
      + dashboard_name = "CPU_Utilization"
      + id             = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

This is passing the variable value including the escape characters like

```
"\"SELECT AVG(CPUUtilization) FROM SCHEMA(\"AWS/EC2\", InstanceId) WHERE InstanceId = 'i-0d9af97eeeaca30a5'\", \"label\": \"Query1\", \"id\": \"q1\""
```

This is causing the query to be invalid in the dashboard

i am expecting it to be passed in its raw form, without the escape sequence like

```
 aws_cloudwatch_dashboard.metrics will be created
  + resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "metrics" {
      + dashboard_arn  = (known after apply)
      + dashboard_body = jsonencode(
            {
              + widgets = [
                  + {
                      + height     = 6
                      + properties = {
                          + metrics = [
                              + [
                                  + {
                                      + expression = "SELECT AVG(CPUUtilization) FROM SCHEMA("AWS/EC2", InstanceId) WHERE InstanceId = 'i-0d9af97eeeaca30a5'", "label": "Query1", "id": "q1"
                                    },
                                ],
                            ]
                          + period  = 300
                          + region  = "eu-west-1"
                          + stacked = false
                          + stat    = "Average"
                          + title   = ""
                          + view    = "timeSeries"
                        }
                      + type       = "metric"
                      + width      = 6
                      + x          = 0
                      + y          = 0
                    },
                ]
            }
        )
      + dashboard_name = "CPU_Utilization"
      + id             = (known after apply)
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try using single quotes: `"${var.query['CPU_Utilization']}" }`

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing inside a string is an interpolation statement, not only is it an antipattern, but terraform will give you a warning.

```
"metrics": [
    [ { "expression": var.query["CPU_Utilization"] } ]
],
```

will do the same thing without an issue. If you want to simplify it further, you can refer to your value as `var.query.CPU_Utilization`